# I don`t understand why this will not work, and I cant figure it out myself

Tags: vb.net, text, timer

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Label1.Text += 1
    Timer2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

I don`t understand why this will not work, and I cant figure it out myself. Help please?

Comment: I am sorry, don't understand either

Comment: In what way does it not work, does it throw an exception? If so, can you provide the exception information?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  how does it fail? see [Ask]  we are not mind readers and `I don`t understand` is not a question

Comment: @plutonix Don't forget about option strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `Label1` to increment every `tick` then you would want to do something like this

```
Dim count as integer

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    count = count + 1
    Label1.Text = count.ToString()
    Timer2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

And if course you would have to re-enable your timer somewhere for it to invoke the `tick` event again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to increment the value by 1 and display it on Label1 try the below code:-

```
int count = 0;

count = count + 1;

Label1.Text = count;
```